# get tetrahedron centroid velocity if vertex velocities known

Tags: mathematics

If i have a tetrahedron and i know the velocities of the 4 vertices, how can I find the velocity of the Centroid?

I know how to get the result if i know the velocity of the Centroid (i can use Barycentric coordinates to find the vertex velocities).